# Unable to find control

Tags: autoit

I want to find and click a button using Autoit. I tried AutoIt Window Information Tool but the button is not recognized so `ControlClick()` fails.

The button is active on the current window but `Send("Enter")` does not work. Tried using `MouseClick()` but the window does not appear in the same place every time, and I tried this script:

```
$hWnd = WinWait("vcredist_x86")
WinWaitActive("vcredist_x86")
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASS FROM AUTOITINFO]", "Left", 1)
```

but neither of them works. Is there any other way to identify and click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When AutoIt Window Information Tool failed me I had success using the text property of the button/ui control:

```
ControlClick($hwin, '', '[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Cancel]')
```

Experiment with "&" in front of one of the characters (underlined by Windows to indicate an <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> shortcut), so try "&Cancel" instead of "Cancel". If that fails try [`ControlFocus()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlFocus.htm) first:

```
ControlFocus($hwin, '', '[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Cancel]')
ControlClick($hwin, '', '[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Cancel]')
```

Inspecting .exe files for GUI resources (using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) for example) may expose text/properties of a control. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If both version of `AutoItWindowInfo`(32 and 64bit) don't "see" the control you need to automate, here is what you can do:

**Method 1 - Sending keystrokes:**

1. Activate the window with `WindowActivate`
2. Send a number of TABs until the control is focused(if its not initially)
3. `Send` ENTER or SPACE

**Method 2 - `MouseClick`:**

1. Activate the window
2. Get the coordinates of a control relative to the application window(position the window at 0,0. Open `Autoit Window Info`, click on Mouse tab and get the position of the button). That position is usually always the same
3. When your code is running it must get the window position with `WinGetPos` and then add control position you got in step 2. That's your clicking position.

**Method 3 - `PixelSearch`(If the control has unique color):**

1. Get the desired color with `AutoIt Window Info`(mouse tab)
2. Search it using `PixelSearch`
3. Click the coords you got

**Method 4 - ImageSearch:**

1. Get `ImageSearch` UDF and DLL
2. Make a picture of the button
3. Search and click it

**NOTE: Sometimes you need to give your script Admin rights in order to automate certain windows.**

Comment: I tried using this WinActivate("WindowTitle")
sleep(2000)
WinGetPos, X, Y, , , WindowTitle
X+= 412
Y+= 169
MouseClick("&Yes" [,%X%, %Y%]) -- but this displayed an error showing unable to parse line. what am i missing here?

Comment: @Rahulk What language is that? It most certainly is not Autoit. Take a look at WinGetPos and AutoIt sintax https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetPos.htm